# is it possible to create a weighted gantt chart in R?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, social-networking, sna

I have some network data that describes connections between individuals over time and the edges are weighted. I'm interested in looking at how the weights of the edges change over time. To do so I was planning to make a gantt chart with the thickness of each line indicating the strength of the connection. Does anyone know if it is possible to create such a plot in R? I've included example code and a representation of the type of plot I would like to produce below:

```
id <- c('a-b','a-c', 'b-c')
t1 <- c(1,0,2)
t2 <- c(2,1,1)
t3 <- c(1,1,0)
df <- cbind (id, t1,t2,t3)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want to try the riverplot package for this?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach thanks! I'll have a look